# UNIKONG goes off the edge of my screen so that I can't see its bottom

Tags: bug, status-norepro, unikong

In the game `UNIKONG` I have sadly found that the game is partly off my screen so that I can't see the bottom of it (I have tried scrolling down etc, it does work). And though in the beginning levels this is not so much of a problem, in the later ones where the trolls and things are on the levels further down, this does become a problem as I can't see them nor the guy I am playing as. Here is a screenshot:

[image: UNIKONG goes off bottom of screen]

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18 and using my browser Firefox 45. I have blocking plugins, but it still didn't work even once I had turned them all off...

Comment: Looks like your screen resolution height is less than 700 pixels, don't think there's anything SE can or should do. Adding scroll to the game is pointless, and making it smaller would harm the experience for all others, who have normal screen resolution.

Comment: Congratulations, you've unlocked the extra special challenge mode.

Comment: *Now that Adam made it into a challenge, reducing screen resolution... waiting for bonus points...* :D

Comment: @ShadowWizard: What about an option to make it full screen? Then it would start at the top of the screen...

Comment: @ParanoidPanda it would only give you 25 pixels, but easily doable via browser console, just type this: `$("#unikong-modal").css("top", "0px");`

Comment: @ShadowWizard: It's fine, I figured out how to make it work and show fine... I just made Firefox go full screen.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda cheers, worth posting a self answer. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, it's fine, I've just added it to the answer which covers most of it anyway, my answer couldn't be as well explained as that one, and to make it so I would probably have to steal some stuff from that one so I rather just leave it all as it is. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Anyway, what am I going to do now? Edit it out of the answer I edited it into and post it? People would then just think I am stealing the stuff and the edit would be rejected. :D

Comment: @ParanoidPanda didn't see you added to the answer. Well, better leave it at that I guess. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I got the same problem, with the same configuration as you. Simply press

```
Ctrl -
```

That zooms out, so you can see all of it.

To get back to regular zoom afterwards, you can either press `Ctrl +` to zoom in, or `Ctrl 0` to go back to the default zoom.

Alternatively, You can also try making Firefox full screen by going to the `menu` button in the top right hand corner, and clicking the `Full screen` button, this should remove the top bar etc and give you the most amount of space without changing the zoom levels. To exit full screen just do the same as you did to enter it.

Most likely, your screen is a little too small, like on a lot of laptops using 1366 by 768 (like mine). The game itself is just 700px, but a some of the screen height in your browser is used by toolbars and the like.

UNIKONG!

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question.

Comment: -1 for actually answering the question

Comment: You can also press F11 to enter Full Screen in Firefox.

Answer (score 11):

Obviously you didn't read the minimum requirements...

of browsing the internet in 2016.

Comment: Wait, so it means the game works on an Apple Watch? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard does *anything* work on an Apple Watch?

Comment: @Haney probably some sort of a Clock app? ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizard the Apple Watch doesn't have web browser capabilities

Comment: @Quill this should not stop Haney... ;-)

Comment: It's quite possible to have this problem on a brand-new laptop. The going form factor these days is 1366x768; subtract the browser toolbars at the top and the taskbar at the bottom, and you're left with maybe 670 pixels of actual usable screen height. It doesn't help that the game adds a 20 pixel top margin, and totally ignores it if you try to scroll the window down.

Comment: Why are people voting this up? If you have a very high-end laptop or if you're using a desktop with three enormous monitors, bully for you, but that doesn't mean those of us with ordinary laptops are somehow inferior beings who shouldn't be allowed to use the internet. Yes, I get that this is just a frivolous April Fools game, but the attitude displayed in this post is still unacceptable.